# C++ Template constructor, why is copy constructor being called?

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I have a class with a template constructor, and the code is actually calling the *copy* constructor, after the default-constructor, which does not make sense to me as the type is incorrect.

For example:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A(void); // default constructor
    A(const A& other); // copy constructor
    template<class TYPE>
    A(const TYPE& object_to_ref);  // template constructor
};
```

This template constructor ***works*** (is properly called in other cases), but is not properly recognized as the "correct" constructor from another template function:

```
template<class TYPE>
A& CreateA(const TYPE& object_to_ref)
{
  // THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER SPECIALIZED WITH "A", ONLY WITH "B" !!
  return *new A(object_to_ref);  // CALLS "A::A(const A&)" !!??
}
```

Example fail:

```
B my_b;
A& my_a = CreateA(my_b);  // "A::A(const A&)" called, not "A::A(const B&)"!
```

This does not make sense to me.  The types are wrong to match the copy constructor.  What happened?  (MSVC2008)

My work-around is to not use the template constructor in this case:

```
template<class TYPE>
A& CreateA(const TYPE& object_to_ref)
{
  A* new_a = new A(); //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
  new_a->setObjectToRef(object_to_ref); //OTHER TEMPLATE MEMBER FUNCTION
  return *new_a;
}
```

**QUESTION:  Why was the template constructor not called in this case?**

(Work-around seems to behave properly, do you suggest an alternative?)

**EDIT:**  `B` is unrelated, with no conversions specified between `B` and/or `A`:

```
class B
{
};
```

Comment: Tangential note: Code that does `return *new` is almost always a bad idea...

Comment: For values of almost that are absurdly close to 100%.

Comment: If `B` is implicitly convertible to `A` then this happens because the compiler finds a matching constructor without needing to ever generate the template code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil

Comment: I can't reproduce that with GCC. Regardless of whether `B` inherits from `A`, the template constructor is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide definition of `B`, so I'm going ahead assuming that `A` is `B`'s ancestor and `B` can be implicitly cast to `A`. In this case your template for `B` is not being instantiated, because there is a perfectly suitable call already.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You probably oversimplified your example. Is there any other implicit method of converting B to A? Like `operator A ()`?

Comment: You were right: Didn't make sense, I oversimplified. There were more `template<>==>traits==>template<>` conversions going on, and one of them was unexpected-but-legitimate, ultimately causing the copy-constructor to be invoked in this case. My fault! (GOOD! IT WAS DRIVING ME CRAZY.)