# return value vs return reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, return-value

It seems like that returning reference is not a good practice ([Is the practice of returning a C++ reference variable, evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil)).

For this example, which would be better: return reference or return value?

```
class A
{
    B b;
public:
    B getB() {return b;} // ??? return value
    B& getB() {return b;} // ??? return reference;
};
```

I guess it's OK to return reference as the returned value is still in memory, but I'm not sure what normally C++ programmers do. Are there any guidelines on when to return value vs when to return reference (or pointer)?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do: do you want the caller to refer to your class' data or not?

Comment: If it helps any, I pretty much always return a value.

Comment: @juanchopanza: in any case, it's better not to give a mutable reference to the caller.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agreed, in general, no. That is where "what you want to do" comes in. You need to have compelling reasons to do it.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: they completely fail to mention the case of an object's attribute though...