# "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type..." Error in clone() function

Tags: c++, templates, clone

Good day

I am busy to implement linear data structure in c++. I am struggeling with my clone() function. The one line code seems in order for me, but maybe the error is in the copy constructor.
The error I am getting:
linkedList.C:22:32: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘LinkedList&’ from an rvalue of type ‘LinkedList*’
  return new LinkedList(*this);

```
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::clone()
{
    return new LinkedList<T>(*this);
}

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& other)
{

    Node<T>* newNode;
    Node<T>* current;
    Node<T>* trailCurrent;

    if(head != NULL)
        clear();
    if(other.head == NULL)
        head = NULL;
    else
    {
        current = other.head;
        head = new Node<T>(current->element);
        head->next = NULL;

        trailCurrent = head;
        current = current->next;

        while(current != NULL)
        {
            newNode = new Node<T>(current->element);
            trailCurrent->next = newNode;

            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first, it seems to me that you initialize a reference with a pointer, don't you?

Comment: The function is delcared to return a LinkedList<T>&, but your code returns a LinkedList<T>*.  There's a type mismatch, so the compiler barfs at you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your clone function to:

```
template<class T>
LinkedList<T>* LinkedList<T>::clone()
{
    return new LinkedList<T>(*this);
}
```

Remember to free the memory after calling the clone function.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is just, we may not alter the header file (so we may not change the function prototype)

Comment: @Mat The thing is.. that thing isn't relevant. This is the correct fix (barring smart pointers and RAII modeling, which is really the *right* way to do this). The instructor that provided that header to you leaves but-one option for properly cleaning up that dynamic allocation (`delete &refvar;`) and that option leaves open a massive whole of a memory leak if used incorrectly, which would be an easy mistake. Maybe the author of that header should be sitting on the other side off the classroom.

Comment: Whoever wrote that header is an idiot.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil