# C++ const function error

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, constants

I am quite new to oop in c++ and I came across the following piece of code while surfing the net:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class cls
{int x;
public: 
    cls(int i=3) {x=i;}

    int &f() const{ return x;}
};
int main()
{
    const cls a(-3);
    int b=a.f();
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to run the code, it crashes due to the f function. Now I am not quite sure what is going on there and why it crashes, so I would need someone to enlighten me a little bit on the subject.

Comment: ^^^^^ Nonsense!

Comment: @BatCoder So, it will return a reference to said variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the practice of returning a C++ reference variable, evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil)

Comment: What is this: `const cls a(-3);` and `cls(int i=3) {x=i;}`

Comment: On the other hand, your code [doesn't even compile](https://ideone.com/C7iIyn). What compiler has been used to compile this code?

Comment: @FirstStep 1st statement - construction of const object. 2nd statement - definition of constructor having an optional parameter. What exactly is wrong with those 2 lines, in your opinion?

Comment: _@Vasile_ Please remember always to post the exact error messages you get from your compiler.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The question actually asks about how to fix the compiler error :P

Comment: "And when I try to run the code, it crashes due to the f function." <- no it doesn't... the code, as shown, doesn't even *COMPILE*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As mentioned by NikBougalis - no, it doesn't. It talks about crashing (_And when I try to run the code, it crashes due to the f function._), and crashing != compiler error.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Define _crashing_ please. I don't know such term used seriously or professionally at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your function is declared as `const` you can't return a non `const` reference to a member variable unless you mark it as `mutable`.

To fix your code write either

```
class cls
{ 
    mutable int x;
 // ^^^^^^^
public: 
    cls(int i=3) {x=i;}

    int &f() const{ return x;}
};
```

or return a `const` reference.

```
class cls
{ 
    int x;
public: 
    cls(int i=3) {x=i;}

    const int &f() const{ return x;}
 // ^^^^^
};
```

---

Using `mutable` needs to be taken with a grain of salt, it would break up the encapsulation of your class, and allow your class internals to be changed via the reference you handed out.

Comment: int f() const{ return x;}  also ok

Comment: @KenmanTsang yes in _this_ case it is ok and, in fact, it's probably advisable (copying an `int` is easy). But returning a copy isn't always a good idea or even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a non `const` reference to a `const`. The `const` member function makes the variable `x` non `const` when it accesses it.

There seems no need to return a reference, and in fact it is a bad practice.  If you need to change your internal `int` it makes more sense to add a setter:

```
class cls
{
    int x;
public: 
    cls(int i=3) { set(i); }
    void set (const int val) { x=val; }
    int f() const{ return x; }
};
```